# Sitecore Content Editor - Update to standard values on templates not being reflected in instances

Tags: templates, caching, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

When updating the standard values of a data template and saving the change, the updated value isn't being reflected in the instance(s) of the data template, until the cache is cleared.

This is happening across all data templates, and isn't due to the standard value being overwritten within the instance(s).

For example, in a base page template that is inherited by the content page template, there is a field that contains an email address.

After creating a new content page instance within the content tree, the email  field is correctly set to the standard value (and has **[standard value]** next to the field name label).

After going back to the base page template, updating the email address and saving the item, the value in the content page instance is not updated, however it still has the **[standard value]** label next to the field.

The value of the field is not updated to reflect the base template until the cache is cleared (currently using the http://localhost/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx) page and using the 'Clear all' button.

Why is the standard value being cached within the content editor, and how can we prevent that from happening?

**UPDATE**

When attempting to reset the content item's field value to the standard value (using the ribbon command Versions -> Reset), the value of the field in the standard value box is also showing the cached standard value, and not the value that has been updated/saved in the data templates standard values.

Comment: Anything interesting in your Sitecore log files?

Comment: Also, did you do any upgrades lately?

Comment: This was working previously and since starting the project we have kept inline with the latest upgrades (recently upgraded to 8.1 update 2) , so it's a bit tricky to tell if one of the updates caused the problem/when it started.

Comment: The logs don't seem to have any definitive entries that might point to the issue, aside from the following regular entry in the error.log - "ERROR There is no appropriate index for /sitecore/social/Messages -  - {DBB82699-FEE0-4A1E-9B52-FACC436925C6}. You have to add an index crawler that will cover this item"

Comment: @HaydnChapman Did you ever find a solution for this? Its driving me nuts.

Comment: @EthanSchofer - unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

In the content editor choose the data item, from the ribbon select the version tab and click the reset button (make sure standard fields are visible).

Select the layouts field and reset it to standard values.

This will show if you have values setup on the standard values correctly.

Comment: I've attempted to reset the standard values of the field (assuming it wasn't pulling it through correctly), but the value shown in the box representing the standard value also contains the cached value, so resetting it doesn't change anything. The problem appears to be that the standard value itself is being cached so every instance of the data template correctly pulls through a standard value that was present at the time the cache was created, and updating the data template has no effect until the cache is cleared (after which all instances are updated to reflect the correct value)

Comment: Usually it updates by itself on Master, and caching issues are usually with the Web database. I do remember though having an issue with Standard values, as presentation showing Standard values was not changing, even that underlying presentation on Standard values is being changed. In my case I believe it was due to multiple inheritance and upgrade. Resetting it all did help I believe, but I will need to ask around, just in case.